# Is there a way to test if all the numbers in an array are bigger than A, and if so replace it by an array of the same length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to build something that analyse my webcam to highlight the pixel that aren't black (to do some tracking autonomously)

i've tried with OpenCV to test like so : `np.where(np.all(img>150,2),255,0)` where img is the camera feed, but i'd like to do that:
`np.where(np.all(img>150,2),np.array(0,255,0),img)`
so only the picture that where found as 'not black' are green and the other are the same as before and not white or black.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while 1:
    ret_val, image = camera.read()
    if not ret_val:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        camera.release()
        break
    img=image[len(image)//2:len(image)]
    A=np.where(np.all(img>150,2),255,0)
    cv2.imshow("output", np.uint8(A))
```

I'd like to have A as an array(n,m,3) and not array(n,m) where n,m are length and width
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you'd like to replace all pixels where the three color channels are above 150 with a green pixel? So any pixel with all channels > 150 becomes a pixel with RGB color `(0, 255, 0)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to convert the "not black" pixels to green (where "not black" means the R, G, and B values are all above 150).

The simple answer to your question would be to replace this:

`A=np.where(np.all(img>150,2),255,0)`

with

```
A = img.copy()
A[np.where(np.all(A > 150, 2))] = np.array([0, 255, 0])
```

The `np.where(np.all(A > 150, 2))` returns the indices of all "not black" pixels, so you are assigning the value [0, 255, 0] to these indices. All other pixels are left the same.

You can also do this in-place to avoid creating another array if you can modify `img`:

```
img[np.where(np.all(img > 150, 2))] = np.array([0, 255, 0])
```

Comment: Do u know if there is a way to find things objects with numpy or a faster way than doing it by myself with For and everything ?

Comment: You should look into object detection with Python. Here's an example tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/